# Different Robes (colours)

Tags: monk

Why do Mahayana and Theravada monks wear different robes (colours)? I understand the colour of Theravada robes represent the colour used in the time of the Buddha. What is the meaning of the yellow/red in mahayana Buddhism?

Comment: Did you see this question? http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1642/what-is-the-meaning-behind-different-robe-colors

Comment: great, is is a duplication indeed. I have tried to close it, but it didnt work